# glide update empties glide.lock

Tags: go, glide-golang

In my golang project, `glide update` command clears out my glide.lock file instead of updating my dependencies. Can anyone help?

Let me explain in details.
My golang project is set up correctly,
1. I am on Windows
2. source code is under GOPATH/src/github.com/myName/repoName/
3. special: Since I am syncing to my private repo on Github, I have this reroute setting in .gitconfig

```
[url "git@github.com:"]
insteadOf = https://github.com/
```

4. I can do `glide get` normally

Issues: prior to `glide up`, my vendor folders have dependencies and my glide.lock looks like this,

[image]

Now if I either do `glide up` or `glide update github.com/name/chaintest0/blockchain`, the glide.lock would look like being cleared.

[image]

Also the vendor folder would be cleared. However, glide.yaml still looks normal.

Now I `glide get` to keep updating. This would work until dependencies get big..

So am I using `glide up` in a wrong way, or is it just a glide bug?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out. Just my own noob question. When I import packages in a local project, I can just import and do not have to `glide get` from Github.

I do not really need a dependency. This is why glide.lock is empty.